# Cost allocation in R

Tags: r, cost-surface, location-allocation

**Background**

I have been scratching my head for a while now on how to carry out cost allocation in R. I do know that there is a really useful package (namely 'gdistance') that can be used for cost distance calculation, but I could not wrap my head around how to start approaching cost allocation.

I came across a thread [LINK](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-July/012208.html) in which the following useful reproducible code has been provided by the author of 'gdistance' himself:

```
costAll <- function(fromCoords, cost)
{
  aC <- stack(cost,cost)
  cT <- transition(cost, mean, 8)
  cT <- geoCorrection(cT, scl=FALSE)
  for(i in 1:dim(fromCoords)[1]) {aC <- stack(aC, accCost(cT, fromCoords[i,]))}
  func <- function(x) which(x == min(x))
  aC <- dropLayer(aC,1:2)
  alC <- calc(aC, func)
  return(alC)
}

fromCoords <- cbind(c(-80,50),c(50,-80))
cost <- raster(ncol=36,nrow=18)
cost <- setValues(cost,rep(1,times=ncell(cost)))
cA <- costAll(fromCoords, cost)

plot(cA)
points(fromCoords)
```

**Question**

That code (while extremely useful) is not originally explained in detail, and remains (my opinion here) quite obscure to the average R user. Can anyone here help breaking it down and provide some explanation chunk by chunk?
I am referring to the code inside the costAll() function.

**EDIT**

In order for my question to be less generic, I would like to know the rationale of the following part, which is not clear to me:

```
  for(i in 1:dim(fromCoords)[1]) {aC <- stack(aC, accCost(cT, fromCoords[i,]))}
  func <- function(x) which(x == min(x))
  aC <- dropLayer(aC,1:2)
  alC <- calc(aC, func)
```

Comment: Have the help pages for the gdistance functions (eg help(transition)) not helped?

Comment: Thank you. I am going to amend the question to make it less generic and to avoid being downvoted further.

Comment: Do you understand what each of the lines do, or are you stuck with the reason for doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some things in the function I don't quite understand, and I'd probably do this a different way, but here's my thoughts:

This line makes a stack by stacking `cost` on top of itself. This sets up a stack on which we are going to further stack the cost rasters for each of the points we have been given. I don't know why two copies of `cost` are stacked here, one would seem to suffice. After stacking the cost rasters on here we're going to chop these two off (see later):

```
  aC <- stack(cost,cost)
```

Compute the transition matrix and apply spatial lat-long correction:

```
  cT <- transition(cost, mean, 8)
  cT <- geoCorrection(cT, scl=FALSE)
```

Now loop over our test points and compute the cost. Stack the cost on top of the `aC` stack that we built earlier. This pattern for building a stack means you don't need to initialise your stack for the first time in the loop, but it does mean you have to chop the "seed" layers off afterwards (see later):

```
  for(i in 1:dim(fromCoords)[1]) {
    aC <- stack(aC, accCost(cT, fromCoords[i,]))
   }
```

I'd probably use `lapply` to make a list of `accCost` results and then make a stack out of them. But this method works.

This `func` finds the index of the smallest element of `x`:

```
  func <- function(x) which(x == min(x))
```

so **now** we chop out those first two copies of `cost` so we are left with only the outputs from `accCost`:

```
  aC <- dropLayer(aC,1:2)
```

and now we apply `func` over the stack to see which point is "nearest" in terms of the `accCost` function and our transition matrix:

```
  alC <- calc(aC, func)
```

Comment: Thank you for shedding light on the code. So, the underlying idea is (A) to calculate as many accumulated cost surfaces as the number of start locations. (B) Then, they are stacked one on top of the other (apologies for the colloquial jargon), and (C) then the function `func <- function(x) which(x == min(x))` returns the index of the smallest cost per each group of stacked cells. I am not totally sure if I am figuring out the last step (C) properly. Thank in advance for any further elucidation.

Comment: After dropping the two layers with `dropLayer` you are left with a stack of two layers that are 36x18 pixel maps. The values in the first layer are the distances to the first point, the values in the second layer are the distances to the second point. Applying `func` via the `calc` function looks at each pixel and returns 1 if the first stack has the smallest pixel value, or 2 if the second stack has the smallest pixel value (and so on for bigger stacks). So you get a single-layer raster that is 1 or 2 indicating the nearest point of the `fromCoords` matrix.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, very helpful.

Comment: Hello again. Everything works fine with the code we were discussing about earlier on, but I ran into an issue when the raster is including cells with NA (e.g., a DTM that is including part of the space off a coastline, where sea cells are given NA). As far far I understood, when `func <- function(x) which(x == min(x))` is applied via `alC <- calc(aC, func)`, the NA cells cannot be processed. I tried to use `na.rm=TRUE` inside the `min()` function, but this does not solve the problem since `inf` is returned. Is there any way of running `func <- function(x) which(x == min(x))` excluding NAs?

Comment: Comment to self. After many attempts, and massive web search, I've found that `raster::which.min()` can handle missing values. So, the line `func <- function(x) which(x == min(x))` and `alC <- calc(aC, func)` can be dropped altogether and safely substituted by `alC <- which.min(aC)`.

Comment: This is where I found info about `raster::which.min()`: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742218/problem-with-the-stackapply-function-in-r)